# Flutter camera preview aspect ratio is wrong in mobile browser

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am using [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package in my project.

It works fine on desktop web browser, but in **mobile web browser** there is issue with camera preview.

It is either not displayed at all, or it is displayed with a weird aspect ratio:

[image]

takePicture() function works fine and photos are taken with correct aspect ratio, but the CameraPreview has issues .

Does anybody have idea if it is possible to fix it ?

Environment:
camera: 0.9.7+1
Flutter 2.10.1
Dart 2.16.1

Answer (score 1):

Without code, it's difficult to tell what might be going wrong here. I suspect that the camera view might be inside another widget (such as `Expanded`) that causes it to stretch/squash too much. You can try wrapping it in an `Align` and `AspectRatio` with the expected aspect ratio, to see if that resolves it (though I suppose you'd want to keep the aspect ratio variable in practice).

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRatio: 4/3, // or whatever ratio you wish to try
    child: CameraView(),
  ),
),
```